# C# ftp EndGetRequestStream

Tags: c#, ftp

Hello i have a problem with my FTP Server.
Let me explain:

I made a tool which uploads a .png file to my FTP.
When i upload 2 images with some delay inbetween ofcoursse.. And try to upload the third one. I get a timeout error. I think this is because i need to end the stream. But i am not sure how to use FtpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream. Does anybody has any clue?

Here is my code if you need it:

```
 FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://www.mysite.com/public_html/" + name);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("MyFTPUsername", "MyFTPPassword");
            request.UseBinary = true;
            request.UsePassive = true;
            request.KeepAlive = true;
            shot = sc.CaptureWindow(HandleID);// Here i take a screenshot of my active window
            shot.Save(request.GetRequestStream(), ImageFormat.Png);// Here i upload it to the FTP
            request.EndGetRequestStream();// <--  -   Now i (think) need to end the stream. But i am not sure how to use the parameters
```

Thanks!

( Please let me know if i am not clear enough! )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be calling of request.GetRequestStream() instead of request.EndGetRequestStream() is all you need?

UPDATE:

Sorry, I mean calling of **request.GetResponse()** instead of request.EndGetRequestStream().

Comment: You mean replacing `shot.Save(request.GetRequestStream(), ImageFormat.Png);` with `shot.Save(request.EndGetRequestStream(), ImageFormat.Png);` ?

Comment: Sorry, I had confused method names. I mean calling of request.GetResponse() instead of request.EndGetRequestStream().

Comment: It kinda worked:

First try when i use: `request.GetResponse();` before uploading the image It works.

Second time how ever i get a error message: _The remote server returned an error: (500) Syntax error, command unrecognized._

How ever the third time i use it, it works just fine again. It keeps cycling through the _First Time_ & _Second Time_

Comment: I hope, you do not forgot to dispose your previous request before creating the new one? It can be accomplish simply be calling of Dispose method of response object which has been returned by calling of request.GetResponse() method. For example you can try something like this: request.GetResponse().Dispose().

Comment: Thanks alot mate! Everything is fine now.

:)